# ReactJS Data Flow Issue

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a t-shirt app I'm trying to make. I have a t-shirt parent class component which has two children class components. One child is a shirt form that sends a quantity number value to the parent component when submitted, which then does basic arithmetic to have a total cost value based on the cost of the shirt sent to the other child component which is a shirt message component. This is eventually going to be the check out page. My issue is that l have multiple forms, with one for each shirt. When l pass in both forms, the quantity is sent for all shirts.

My question is this: When I have multiple duplicate child components (forms) sending info (1 quantity value per component) to a parent which then passes it down to another child component (message),  what is the best way to distinguish between the duplicate multiple child components?

Comment: Each of your child groups should have a unique ID, and set the parent component's `state.x[id].y`. Which is now passed as prop to `childgroup[id]`, thus only affecting the other component of the same group.

Comment: Where do I set that unique ID? Is it each time I render an instance of my child component in the parent?

Comment: Are you rendering the children in a loop? If so, you should be adding a `key` attribute to them anyway. Without seeing the relevant code it's kinda hard to give concrete advice though.

Comment: Yeah I am using an if statement to assess the unique IDs. I have added the code here: https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B8_AcbvKxuG-em13YXpKX2JJS3c, if you would like to review it as I tried using key and id with neither working. I am wondering if I need to implement functions like componentWillMount() and componentDidMount(). I dont think these will be necessary yet. I am very confused as this seems like something easy that I am overlooking.

Comment: In your `ShirtForm`'s `onFormSubmit`, call `this.props.onSubmit(this.props.id, quantity);`, then use `handleFormSubmit: function (shirtID, quantity)` to find out which form was submitted.

Comment: That makes perfect sense, but how do I guarantee that the form that I submit has an ID that is unique and that ID always matches the right shirt cost? It seems like this solution is to pass in the ID but that ID would always be the same. It seems like something (function) needs to happen in the ShirtForm that needs to generate unique IDs and then somehow match that up to prices, but I am not sure how to do this.

Comment: Right now you're manually creating the entire shirts part. The solution is to use a component and pass name, image and price to it. This array of shirt components will have a `key` for each element you can use as id. Refer back to my first two comments. (you're basically not fully following proper react patterns; do that and the problem will disappear)

Comment: Sorry as I am new to programming, so I am trying to conceptualize this as I understand what you are saying but am still a bit confused. But since price is directly tied to the input of the form where do I define the price? It seems as though you are hinting at separating the price and quantity but I am still not sure how to link these or how to define the array? Again, I apologize for not completely understanding where I need to define everything and link everything up.

Comment: Also, if I use a component to pass up name, image and price, it would make sense to use a Shirt component to pass all the form, image, and price into so that I can then pass that into the Shirts parent component. What I want to do is have the Shirt component be reusable instead of me having to define each shirt in a separate component. I still feel like its not being fully explained here in terms of what needs to happen to get the ID working and fully binded to a specific price.

Comment: Alright; it took some time but I rewrote your `Shirts` component and added a `Shirt` component. I also added some basic error handling (negative quantities are not allowed) by making the quantity field controlled. I tried to follow React patterns as I learned them. https://mega.nz/#!dAY2wBiB!jczrPUt3s04S5aWE5Ef0F6hTZqKfJqgZAn1WYyZxSZM

Comment: I do have to add that the quantities of the shirts should probably be part of the state of `Shirts`, but it's no big deal to change the code accordingly. Just don't use individual variables but an array.

Comment: Thank you. I think what was needed the whole time was an array, then to pass these values into a component, then loop on that component in the parent component. This makes a lot more sense now that I can see the code.